# Функция info для Дискорд бота на python

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня проблема, помогите, пожалуйста! Когда я ввожу функцию `info`, мне бот отсылает 2 **embed**, а нужно, чтобы он отсылал только один.

```
#информация
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'title', description="",color =0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name="rev",value="перевёрнутый текст", inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name="rp",value="случайная картинка",inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: У Вас проблемы - у меня всё работает. А что вам надо?

Comment: Ввожу команду .info и мне бот отправляет два эмбеда,один с заголовком,а другой с заголовком и списком комманд.

Comment: Мне отправляет сообщение с красным боком, вот такое:  **title
rev
перевёрнутый текст
rp
случайная картинка**

Comment: Где-то за пределами этой функции у вас проблемы

Comment: У меня тоже была такая догадка.Ясно, сейчас посмотрю.

Answer (score 0):

Мне отправляет сообщение с красным боком, вот такое:

**title**

**rev**

перевёрнутый текст

**rp**

случайная картинка.

Где-то за пределами этой функции у вас проблемы.
Попробуйте скопировать только главную часть без команд и только эту команду в новый файл. Должно сработать

Answer (score 0):

Вполне возможно, если вы хостите бота на компьютере, что бот был запущен **2** раза. Только что проверил ваш код, с ним все хорошо, попробуйте перезагрузить ваш компьютер, или в этом роде.

Помимо этого, если вы не пишите в одном `main.py` файлике, попробуйте проверить и остальные. Вполне возможно, там также есть такая команда.

[image: Проверил ваш код на своем боте.]